# Relationship between the client and the company

Tags: python, django, database, model, many-to-many

I have a problem with the relationship between the client and the company.

The requirement is this:

1) A client can be a client from many companies.

2) A company can have many clients.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I read that this should be a ManyToManyField relationship.
But where should it be in the Company model or in the Client model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that this should be a `ManyToManyField` relationship. But where should it be in the `Company` model or in the `Client` model?

That does *not* matter. A many-to-many relation is stored in the database with an extra table that has foreign keys to both models. In your `ManyToManyField` you can give it a name for the relation in reverse:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clients = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='companies')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can query in both directions. For example:

```
some_company.clients.all()
```

is a `QuerySet` to obtain all clients of `some_company`, and:

```
some_user.companies.all()
```

is a `QuerSet` to obtain all `companies of`some_user`. There is no difference at all, since Django will automatically give the relation in reverse a name.